# Do I have to use PHP differently with mobile devices?

Tags: php, html

This is my first PHP-based web project. I have the web part of it working perfectly, but I'm having trouble with the mobile version. (Web hosting on godaddy linux)

**What is the reason for my .php page not displaying? If I change it to .html, it works fine.** 
(I suspect the doctype, but not sure.)
Not sure if this code is necessary, but I'll leave out the body for the sake of space:

```
<?php include_once 'web/config.php'?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN"
"http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>About - Mobile</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<meta name="keywords" content="About - Mobile" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" />
</head>
```

config.php:

```
$link = mysqli_connect($server, $db_user, $db_pass);
mysqli_select_db($link, $database);

// -=-=-=-=-=-=-=[ Getting Variables ]=-=-=-=-=-=-=- //
$query = "SELECT * FROM `misc`";
$result = $link->query($query);
while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
// -=-=-=-=-=-=-=[ Variables ]=-=-=-=-=-=-=- //
$pickupTime = $info['pickupTime'];
$deliveryTime = $info['deliveryTime'];
$minDeliveryPrice = $info['minDeliveryPrice'];
$Gtitle = $info['Gtitle'];
$emailAccount = $info['emailAccount'];
$phone = $info['phone'];
$mailSubject= $info['mailSubject'];
$address = $info['address'];
$city = $info['city'];
$zipcode = $info['zipcode'];
$companyTel = $info['companyTel'];
$companyEmail = $info["companyEmail"];
$facebookLink = $info['facebookLink'];
$twitterLink = $info['twitterLink'];
$googleLink = $info['googleLink'];
$termsOfService = $info['termsOfService'];
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does that really look like valid HTML to you?

Comment: php couldn't care less about what device you're using. php's job is (generally) to generate html. it's up to you to generate the appropriate html for the user's device.

Comment: Are you running this text on the phone itself, or is a mobile version of your site?  Unless you have a server, PHP won't work; it's serverside.

Comment: @JohnConde Yes, I didn't include the body for the sake of space. Not sure what is wrong.

Comment: @AlexanderLozada Hosting w/ linux server

Comment: It's not the body that i am talking about. Not only do you have two doctypes but they're both different! Same for your opening html tag.

Comment: Create a `check.php` file with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and see if anything pops up. If nothing shows up, then your server's not setup to handle PHP.

Comment: You could also put a semi-colon at the end `<?php include_once 'web/config.php'; ?>` see if that makes it kick in. Yours doesn't have one right now `<?php include_once 'web/config.php'?>` @jdish123

Comment: We also need to know what's inside `config.php` otherwise, the black golf ball will most probably end up in the lake tonight. @jdish123

Comment: @Fred-ii- config.php just contains variables. Should I post it anyways?

Comment: It might prove to be helpful. @jdish123

Comment: Why do you have 2 html tags? Where is your body tag? where is your  closing html tag? I suggest you learn html first.

Comment: @Krimson Like I said, I just posted the head for the sake of space. The body is irreverent to the question. Thanks for the sharp eyes though!

Comment: [`Did you try this?`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213521/do-i-have-to-use-php-differently-with-mobile-devices#comment33726325_22213521) @jdish123

Comment: The problem is most likely with this line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` --- When it was inside a test file I did up, it generated a parse error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'version' (T_STRING)`, but displayed correctly when removed. @jdish123

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for all the help! I'm now using the check.php, Very helpful, Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. So, is everything working now? @jdish123

Answer (score 3):

PHP is executed at server side, as long as the PHP script renders valid HTML (this however doesn't seem the case), the phones won't care.

In case PHP code is received by a browser, something is wrong with the sever (for instance you didn't install PHP at server side, or the webserver doesn't know when to call PHP to generate a webpage)

A browser never receives the PHP code (otherwise it would be easy for instance to hijack databases since the PHP code has somehow the password).

Comment: ok, so what's the reason for the page not displaying at all? If I change it to .html, it loads perfectly fine. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Just modified the answer, are you sure you installed for instance Apache or another webserver application that can handle PHP code?

Comment: Yeah, I have it working w/ php on the desktop version, so it should work with this, right?

Comment: Indeed, but what do you mean with the desktop version. Do you run the code on your localhost, a remote machine? More information would help solving the problem.

Comment: the desktop version is just formatted for the web. I'm hosting w/ a Godaddy linux server. Like I said, its reading the php from the "desktop version". Just not sure why this is any different. Thank you though, you're being very helpful!!

Comment: In that case I think the generated HTML code is not strictly HTML or uses features that are not supported by your smartphone. However you should never receive PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

PHP executes on the server, the client doesn't know it is talking to PHP. You need not change PHP code when targeting mobile platforms.

Your issue appears to be corrupt HTML

```
<?php include_once 'web/config.php'?>
```

We should probably see the `config.php` file to see what is happening in there.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
```

Here you open an `<HTML>` tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN"
"http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Here you open another `<HTML>` tag, this is an issue. You should only have one `<HTML>` tag as your outer node in the document.

```
<head>
<title>About - Mobile</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<meta name="keywords" content="About - Mobile" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" />
</head>
```

You do not close your `<HTML>` tags and you do not have a body to render.

Answer (score 1):

Well since you said you posted only the head. Im just gonna fix your html to at least make it valid. And regarding the php, other answers explain why php doesn't matter when viewing websites in browsers

```
<?php include_once 'web/config.php'?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>About - Mobile</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <meta name="keywords" content="About - Mobile" />
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" />
    </head>
    <body>
    ....
    </body>
</html>
```

If this doesn't work, then I am guessing that this line of php `<?php include_once 'web/config.php'?>` is outputting something which is messing up the html or in other words, make it invalid, so try removing it and then try
Also what do you mean its not displaying? Like nothing shows up? Or does it give an (http and or php) error?

Comment: it's blank. The page loads fine if I take out the php and change the extension to .html, but as soon as I change it to .php, the page is blank even when I take out all the php. Any Ideas? Thanks! @Krimson

Comment: @jdish123 can you tell me whats in your `config.php` file?

Comment: Added it to the question. Thanks!

Comment: @jdish123 Are you sure that your msqli is not generating any error? Whats happens if you remove the first line: `<?php include_once 'web/config.php'?>` and leave the page as php?

Comment: Blank page :/ Even if I delete all php code in the file. Any ideas? @Krimson

Comment: @jdish123 You sad that you have your site hosted on godaddy. So can you send me the link to your site and that way I can try it out myself

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49195/discussion-between-jdish123-and-krimson)